# StringResourceModel only works for label

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket, resourcebundle

I was trying to create a link with the username on it (i.e. dynamic data), and couldn't manage to get the `StringResourceModel` to work with a `Link`.
My code looked something like:

Properties:

```
some.key=User name is: {0}
```

Java:

```
StringResourceModel model = 
    new StringResourceModel("some.key", this, null, new Object[] { getUserName() }); 
add(new Link("someid", model) {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // do something ...
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="someid">some text to replace</a>
```

However, that didn't work, i.e. the text was never replaced.

I tried a different direction, which did work, and looks something like this:

Java:

```
StringResourceModel model = 
    new StringResourceModel("some.key", this, null, new Object[] { getUserName() }); 
Link link;
add(link = new Link("someid") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // do something ...
    }
});

link.add(new LabeL("anotherid", model));
```

HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="someid"><span wicket:id="anotherid">some text to replace</span></a>
```

(the properties file is the same).

My question is, am I right to assume that the `StringResourceModel` doesn't work with `Link`s (I call this an assumption since I didn't see anything about this in the JavaDOC) ?
If not, how can the `StringResourceModel` be used directly with the `Link`, without the mediator `Label` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` parameter in the `Link` constructor isn't meant to be used as a display value. To set the text of the link you need to explicitly add a `Label` to it:

```
Link<Void> link = new Link<Void>("link");
link.add(new Label("label", model);
add(link);
```

and in HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="label"></span></a>
```

The model in the constructor is meant to be used in the onclick method (or similar). For example (from the JavaDoc):

```
IModel<MyObject> model = ...;
Link<MyObject> link = new Link<MyObject>("link", model) {
    public void onClick() {
        MyObject obj = getModelObject();
        setResponsePage(new MyPage(obj));
    }
};
add(link);
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing based on a hunch. Too bad it isn't mentioned in the the Wicket JavaDocs.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you aren't telling wicket to replace the text. You just apply a model to the link without telling wicket what to do with it.
To fix this, you'd need to replace your HTML with something along the lines of

```
<a wicket:id="someid"><wicket:message key="some.key">some text to replace</wicket:message></a>
```

I don't remember the syntax completely and can't try this right now but it should help you anyway.

Comment: This is very similar to what I did initially and didn't work. I'll give it a try later on today though, to make sure I'm not missing anything. Thanks.

Comment: @eitanfar can you explain in what way it "didn't work"? Did you see the unreplaced contents of the wicket message tag? Did you get an error message? Wasn't the model incorporated into your message?

Comment: I saw the resource text, but the parameters weren't resolved. In other words, I saw the text "User name is: {0}". However, this might have been caused by something else (such as the parameter being null or whatever), this is why I want to double check.

Comment: @eitanfar upon further digging, it looks like you can only add a model for a label to an ExternalLink, not a plain Link. If this is not an potion, I think, you'll have to stick to adding a Label.